# Trigger notice/error during SISS Package (T-SQL Task) to "Execution Results" without stopping execution, like php trigger_error("xyz",E_USER_NOTICE)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

Is it possible to generate a User Notice like in PHP (trigger_error("xyz",E_USER_NOTICE)) in a SSIS Package to "Execution Results"?

(PRINT is not shown.)

```
//php//
trigger_error("100 rows effected", E_USER_NOTICE);
```

TSQL Statement used after executing a Data Flow Task in SSIS Package:

```
--T-SQL--
IF @COUNT_A_2 = 0 AND @COUNT_B_2 = 0 
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Import.A_B', 16, 1) -- ######## USER_NOTICE ################

--  recert.A_B befüllen--
INSERT INTO  recert.A_B (A_id, B_id)
SELECT K.A_id AS A_id, L.ID AS B_id
FROM dbo.K AS K
JOIN recert.L AS L ON K.B = L.name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT * FROM recert.A_B AS D 
                    WHERE D.A_id = K.A_id AND K.B = L.name 
                  )
PRINT 'recert.A_B befüllt. / INSERT.A_B'
```

[...]

```
-- Leeren der Tabellen --
DELETE FROM [testdb].[dbo].[W]

END  
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Daten nicht verarbeitet / NO data inserted' 
    RaisError('Daten nicht verarbeitet / NO data inserted',18,1) 
    -- stopps SISS Package. OK.
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the number of affected rows should be available in SSIS. You can for example return the number of affected rows in your SQL statement and load them into a variable using the ResultSet tab of the 'Execute SQL Task' editor.

You can then fire an event (Progress, Information) with the 'Script Task' using one of the following methods:

```
Dts.Events.FireProgress
Dts.Events.FireInformation
```

Add that script task in your control flow, or on the OnPostExecute event handler of the 'Execute SQL Task'.